# Vagrant ошибка There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`

Tags: python, virtualbox, vagrant, консоль

There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "59cd6309-2202-41eb-944f-866cb45a6b23", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Not in a hypervisor partition (HVP=0) (VERR_NEM_NOT_AVAILABLE).
VBoxManage.exe: error: VT-x is disabled in the BIOS for all CPU modes (VERR_VMX_MSR_ALL_VMX_DISABLED)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Совершенно ничего не понимаю, полный новичок, подскажите что сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, ураа, в BIOS была отключена аппаратная виртуализация процессора.

https://itremont.info/programmnoe-obespechenie/62-kak-proverit-podderzhivaet-li-apparatnuyu-virtualizatsiyu-intel-vt-i-amd-v-vash-protsessor/